# ResourceManager Frequent active/standby switchover

Tags: hadoop-yarn

Recently, the active/standby switchover occurs frequently on ResourceManager in the production environment. The ResourceManager finds that the gc interruption takes a long time before the switchover. The detailed logs are as follows:

```
2023-08-28 17:59:50,594 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmcontainer.RMContainerImpl: container_e156_1693206509879_0068_01_000005 Container Transitioned from ACQUIRED to RUNNING
2023-08-28 18:00:39,888 WARN org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 23927ms for sessionid 0x3003deed73af16b
2023-08-28 18:00:39,888 WARN org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 28541ms for sessionid 0x2003df0d3d7f1ce
2023-08-28 18:00:39,888 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 23927ms for sessionid 0x3003deed73af16b, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
2023-08-28 18:00:39,888 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 28541ms for sessionid 0x2003df0d3d7f1ce, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
2023-08-28 18:00:39,889 WARN org.apache.hadoop.util.JvmPauseMonitor: Detected pause in JVM or host machine (eg GC): pause of approximately 22434ms
No GCs detected
2023-08-28 18:00:39,904 INFO SecurityLogger.org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Auth successful for appattempt_1693206509879_0067_000001 (auth:SIMPLE)
2023-08-28 18:00:39,989 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ha.ActiveStandbyElector: Session disconnected. Entering neutral mode...
2023-08-28 18:00:39,989 INFO org.apache.curator.framework.state.ConnectionStateManager: State change: SUSPENDED
2023-08-28 18:00:39,989 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ActiveStandbyElectorBasedElectorService: Lost contact with Zookeeper. Transitioning to standby in 20000 ms if connection is not reestablished.
```

The number of NodeManager nodes is 70 and the JVM is set to (Xmx 16G, Xms 16GB). I hope there are experts who can help with the answer.

Comment: I tried to set the timeout for connecting to zookeeper from 10s to 20s. The problem still occurs.